# How to rectify "Document was used before it was defined" using Jslint

Tags: jslint

I get the following error in *jsLint*:

> 'document' was used before it was defined.

Line that causes the error:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
```

I get why this happens, but I would like my code to be compliant.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If using jsLint in NetBeans IDE, there are options for assuming console, browser and nodeJS are available. Probably other IDEs have the same option.

Answer (score 50):

Place

```js
/*jslint browser:true */
```

in the beginning of the body of your function. Or, alternatively, you may use

```js
/*global document: false */
```

JSLint is for the checking of any javascript code, and the `document` global object does not exists everywhere, so you have to manually tell JSLint that your code is aimed to be executed in browser, and thus `document` global variable is defined. For example, for server-side javascript it is expected for JSLint to report about this error.

Comment: you can put the statement at the top of your file and it will apply to all functions

Comment: jslint --browser file.js

Answer (score 2):

From jslint's website, you can read about a /*global*/ directive that allows you to set variables that are assumed to be declared elsewhere.

Here is an example (put this at the top of the file):

```
/\*global var1,var2,var3,var4,var5\*/
```

or, in starjava's case:

```
/\*global document\*/
```

I'm not actually sure if the `:true` or `:false` is needed, but it looks like it's recommended from what I read on the site. http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Make sure the initial global statement is on the same line as `'/\*'`, or else it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

If all your JS code is supposed to be run from browser then just the add the `--browser` flag.

```
jslint --browser my.js
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using node can add the following line

```
/ * node JSLint: true * /
```

at the start of the script
http://jslinterrors.com/a-was-used-before-it-was-defined/

Answer (score 0):

In cli mode you can use config file:
**jslint.conf**

```
{
    "predef": [
        "module",
        "require",
        "window",
        "document",
        "jQuery",
        "Backbone",
        "Marionette",
        "Modernizr",
        "_",
        "setTimeout",
        "clearTimeout",
        "setInterval",
        "clearInterval"
    ],
    "evil":false,
    "indent":4,
    "vars":true,
    "passfail":false,
    "plusplus":false
}
```

And use jslint with `--config jslint.conf` parameter.