# Javascript JSLint: ADsafe violation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I've overcome a problem of JSLint showing me a "X was used before it was defined" error, by using a global directive as suggested by [Document was used before it was defined solution]this Stack Overflow question[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766201/how-to-rectify-document-was-used-before-it-was-defined-using-jslint):

```
/*global $, document, window, alert, setTimeout*/
```

However, this now produces a new warning: `JSLint: ADsafe violation /*global`.

Has anyone else come across this warning? How can we rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that by referencing globals at all, you're violating the ADsafe subset rules.  If you're not doing that sort of work, then just turn off the option to check for that. (It's the "adsafe" option; just set it to "false".)

```
/*jslint adsafe: false */
```